# Quaternion structure implies dimension divisible by $4$

Tags: linear-algebra, quaternions

A quaternion structure on a real vector space $V$ is a pair of operators $J,K \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ such that $$J^2 = K^2 = -I, \; \; JK = -KJ$$ where $-I$ is the negative identity matrix.

This makes $V$ into a left module over the quaternions and in particular $\mathrm{dim}(V)$ is a multiple of $4$. I wonder if there is a "direct" way to see this, similar to the proof that $\mathrm{dim}(V)$ is even because $\mathrm{det}(J)^2 = (-1)^{\mathrm{dim}\, V}$ is positive.

Comment: You can show $V\cong\Bbb H^n$ as quaternionic vector spaces for some $n$.. Is that "direct"? (Also, if we take $\det$ of both sides of $J^2=-I$, don't we get $\det(J)^2=+1$?)

Comment: @arctictern By "direct" I mean something only using linear algebra over fields. It would be nice to have a proof only using the real vector space structure of $V$, but a proof that the complex dimension of $V$ must be even would also be interesting. I'm not sure how to do either.

Comment: A complex vector space has even real dimension because it will be isomorphic to $\Bbb C^n$ for some $n$. The argument for quaternionic vector spaces is the exact same, only we need to make sure scalars are always applied from one side or the other. The problem with interpreting a quaternionic vector space as a complex one (with $J$ as the imaginary unit) and showing it has even complex dimension, is that $K$ and $J$ don't commute so $K$ will not be a linear operator with respect to the complex structure.

Comment: One possibility would be to observe that the operators $J$ and $K$ generate the obvious group $Q_8$ of order $8$. By Maschke's theorem from representation theory we then know that $V$ splits into a direct product of irreducible $Q_8$-invariant subspaces. Furthermore, the dimensions of those subspaces are at most four. OTOH it seems to me that given a non-zero vector $x\in V$, the vectors $x,Jx,Kx,JKx$ are A) linearly independent (a putative relation leads to the familiar 4x4 determinant with non-vanishing determinant), B) there span is stable under $Q_8$.

Comment: But may be that would be cheating :-). Those facts about the span of $x,Jx,Kx,JKx$ follow without any representation theory, but proving that $V$ is a direct sum of such spaces needs something extra that I cannot see right away.

Answer (score 1):

I have just noticed this old post, but here's a possible "direct" way to see the divisibility by 4:

we know that the existence of J already implies that $\mbox{dim}V$ is even, say $\mbox{dim}V=2n$, and that this gives $V$ the structure of complex vector space with $J$ acting as $i$.

Fix then a complex basis of $V$, say $\{e_1,...,e_n\}$, and consider the real basis of $V$ given by $\{e_1,..., e_n, ie_1,..., ie_n\}$. In such a basis the matrix of $J$ is just the block matrix given by
$$J=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -Id \\
Id & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
From $JK=-KJ$ it follows easily that the matrix of $K$ in such a basis has to be of the form
$$K=\begin{pmatrix} X & Y \\
Y & -X
\end{pmatrix}$$
for some real $n\times n$ matrices $X,Y$.

But then $$\begin{pmatrix} X^2+Y^2 & 0 \\
0 & X^2+Y^2
\end{pmatrix}=K^2=\begin{pmatrix} -Id & 0 \\
0 & -Id
\end{pmatrix}$$
implies that $0\leq \mbox{det}(X^2+Y^2)=(-1)^n$, and so that $n$ has to be even, i.e. that $\mbox{dim}V=2n$ has to be divisible by 4.

P.S. The claimed inequality just comes from $$\mbox{det}(X^2+Y^2)=\mbox{det}((X+iY)(X-iY))=\mbox{det}(X+iY)\overline{\mbox{det}(X+iY)}\geq 0$$